# Setting the first item on a RadSplitButton

Tags: winforms, telerik

I'm new to the usage of the RadSplitButton on Winforms.
I've defined two RadMenuItem and set the DefaultItem to the first item of mine collection but it still shows empty as you can see

[image]

Is there a way that I can set the first item

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RadSplitButton offers a Text property to set its button content:

```
RadSplitButton splitButton = new RadSplitButton();
splitButton.Text = "Fruits";
```

For more information please check the documentation: [Getting Started](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/controls/buttons/splitbutton/working-with-radsplitbutton-items).

Answer (score 1):

Are looking for is content? Like set RadSplitButton.content = "some content"?